# Problems with aireplay-ng

Tags: patch, aircrack-ng

I'm trying to change the channel on monitoring mode interface `mon0` but when I use it in `aireplay-ng` it says it's not on the same channel with AP. I've tried to change the channel with

```
iwconfig mon0 channel #
```

and still get the same message. I read a lot about that issue, and I've found a patch which might eventually resolve the issue. The patch is called `channel-negative-one-maxim.patch` but I don't know how to apply it.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 x64 with Gnome 3. I didn't had that issue before, I think it just popped up after some update. Can someone explain me how to apply that patch? BTW the driver of the wireless adapter is rt2800usb.

PS. Ok, now I'm trying to restore rt2800usb driver, because I figured out how to install the newest driver, but it doesn't work well with airodump-ng. I can't find package with the original rt2800usb driver atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so  - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1598930 and do exactly what is written and it's fixed, THANKS!

Comment: See, a moment like this is why people should not post link-only answers...the Ubuntu Forums are down.